# Check if a method responds to another method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :show_dashboard_menu, only: :index

  def index
    ...
  end

  private

  def show_dashboard_menu
    true
  end
end
```

I want to spread the method show_dashboard_menu across several controllers and check if I need to show a menu for particular actions from the helper method:

My helper:

```
def show_dashboard_menu?
  true if current_action responds to show_dashboard_menu
end
```

And then use it in the view to show or hide the dashboard menu:

```
show_dashboard_menu?
```

Comment: move this method to application controller and it will be accessible over all controllers which are inherited from application_controller, and if you want to access controlller method in helper or views. add this to the end of that controller file       helper_method :show_dashboard_menu?

Comment: OK but how to apply this method from the application controller to only certain actions?

Comment: if you want to apply this action to certain actions. simply add this to your controller file .. => before_action show_dashboard_menu?, only: [#comma seperated action names] in the child controller classes. due to inheritences this method wil be called automatically for child class because it will search first in child class if not found go to the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby objects have a method called respond_to? (take care that if for methods and attributes)

```
2.2.1 :001 > 1.respond_to?("to_s")
 => true 
2.2.1 :002 > 1.respond_to?("each")
 => false 
2.2.1 :003 > [].respond_to?("each")
 => true 
2.2.1 :004 > [].respond_to?("something")
 => false 
2.2.1 :005 >
```

or you can allso ask just for methods or public_methods

```
2.2.1 :010 > 2.methods.include?(:real)
 => true 
2.2.1 :011 > 2.public_methods.include?(:real)
 => true 
2.2.1 :012 > 2.methods
 => [:to_s, :inspect, :-@, :+, :-, :*, :/, :div, :%, :modulo, :divmod, :fdiv, :**, :abs, :magnitude, :==, :===, :<=>, :>, :>=, :<, :<=, :~, :&, :|, :^, :[], :<<, :>>, :to_f, :size, :bit_length, :zero?, :odd?, :even?, :succ, :integer?, :upto, :downto, :times, :next, :pred, :chr, :ord, :to_i, :to_int, :floor, :ceil, :truncate, :round, :gcd, :lcm, :gcdlcm, :numerator, :denominator, :to_r, :rationalize, :singleton_method_added, :coerce, :i, :+@, :eql?, :remainder, :real?, :nonzero?, :step, :quo, :to_c, :real, :imaginary, :imag, :abs2, :arg, :angle, :phase, :rectangular, :rect, :polar, :conjugate, :conj, :between?, :nil?, :=~, :!~, :hash, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :singleton_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
```

So in your ApplicationController you will able to do something like

```
def show_dashboard_menu?
  self.respond_to? "show_dashboard_menu"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before_action` in `ApplicationController` and define `show_dashboard_menu?` method in your specific controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action only: :index do |ctrl| 
    @show_dashboard_menu = ctrl.try(:show_dashboard_menu?) 
  end
end

class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def show_dashboard_menu?
    whatever_logic
  end
end
```

Then use `@show_dashboard_menu` variable in a view.
One thing I don't like is that `show_dashboard_menu?` has to be public. However you can use attribute instead of method and set it in before_action.